# can't understand the behavior of the trait

Tags: scala

I have defined a trait like following,

```
trait Log {
  val logEnabled: Boolean
  def log(msg: String) {
    if(logEnabled) {
       println(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

and want to use like following:

```
def log(enabled: Boolean)(msg: String) = new Log(){
  val logEnabled = enabled
}
implicit val enabled = true;
val log1 = log(true) _
log1("hi, world")
```

but the result is blank, nothing print out,  not what I thought what it should be.

Could someone please explain what the mechanism behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above, `log1("hi, world")`, actually doesn't call the `Log.log` function, but results *just* in an instance of `Log`. This is because calling the curried function:

```
def log(enabled: Boolean)(msg: String) = new Log(){ ... }
val log1 = log(true) _
```

results in a function that, given a string, would return a Log.

What you probably want is:

```
trait Log {
  val logEnabled: Boolean
  def apply(msg: String) {
    if(logEnabled) {
      println(msg)
    }
  }
}

def log(implicit enabled: Boolean) = new Log(){
     val logEnabled = enabled
   }
implicit val enabled = true
val log1 = log
log1("hi, world")
```

Notice how apply method is called on Log instead.